# Syntax of proxy directive in virtual host - httpd

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd

I came across a cofig file at work, but I am unsure if the syntax is correct. Based  on the documentation from apache:https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy
the proxy directive's context is "virtual host", which is absolutely correct. It seems it's perfectly fine to have a config like this one below (which is the one I came across at work)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myexample.com

  Redirect / https://myexample.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myexample.com

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile locationofcert.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile locationofkey.key


  ProxyTimeout 300
  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://myexample.com:7990/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://myexample.com:7990/
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

My specific question is about this part:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

I have noticed in some examples in github that, this proxy directive is placed inside a Location tag like this:

```
<Location />
       ProxyPass http://localhost:9000/
       ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9000/
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
</Location>
```

I am trying to find out what the correct syntax is. Any links to documentation would be appreciated too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax-wise, both are correct. Choice should be entirely based on the requirement.

It is also possible to place the whole `<Location>` block inside a `<VirtualHost>`. For instance, your above code can be rewritten as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName myexample.com
     Redirect / https://myexample.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName myexample.com
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile locationofcert.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile locationofkey.key   
     ProxyTimeout 300
     ProxyRequests on
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     <Location />
          ProxyPass http://myexample.com:7990/
          ProxyPassReverse http://myexample.com:7990/
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks, do you by chance have a link to some documentation where I can check it out and learn more?